# jQuery autocomplete works on test webserver but not on production webserver

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am attempting to implement a jquery autocomplete feature for my corporate website only to find that while everything works fine on my local webserver it doesn't work when I upload it to my production web server. I have already gone through the typical troubleshooting routine of ensuring that all the required files are uploaded and configured correctly, so I can safely discard this as the source of the problem.

Using FireBug to find clues of what was going on, I took a look at my HTTP headers and found that on both my local webserver and production webserver the Request headers seemed to be identical.  Here is the Request header:

> Accept    application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
>   Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
>   Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
>   Connection  keep-alive
>   Content-Length  56
>   Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
>   Cookie  pemco_tpl=pemco; __utma=249376134.120577909.1319559821.1335888590.1335890492.201; __utmz=249376134.1335369030.191.2.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); __utmc=249376134; csrf_cookie_name=822b8ced4d8a7bc49d02b11f44efcb15; ci_session=UmYHbQs0VmsGfQckUDxRYwMyAD8Fc1UgXGUNdQMrVT0BbQxpXANWawIzVSdaalcjATtTMFUxBz5TcANkVjBabVE8DmdQaVA0VGYKOAxtUmdSMgdlCzdWYAY2B2BQPlFrA2AAYQUyVWZcZA0zA2BVZwE0DGZcZVZkAjZVJ1pqVyMBO1MyVTMHPlNwA29WcloDUWwOYVBvUCNUMgpyDH9SJFI8ByQLOlZgBjIHbVAkUWADMgA1BX9VYlwyDTIDdlVnATIMKVxtVjECZ1UnWmpXIwE7UzJVMwc%2BU3ADc1ZxWjlRfw5aUGpQNlQyCm8MeFIkUjwHJAs6VmYGNAdtUCRRHwNtAH8FOFU%2FXGwNZwN3VWEBLAw3XHxWKgIAVWxaP1c0AW5TdFVwByRTHANSViJaalEjDjRQMFBxVAAKTgxbUjBSMwdsCyBWIwZwB21QN1FjAywANQV4VXNcRw1jAztVPwFtDChcblYyAmZVNVphV2EBMVMyVSMHQlM7A3RWZ1o6UWIOfVAkUGBUZgovDDxSJFI8ByQLOlZgBjUHbVAkUT4DYwB2BSVVDFxhDWUDLFU9AXQMblwoVnsCdVU%2BWjhXagEwUzBVMAcxU2oDP1YyWmhRNA41UDBQLA%3D%3D; __utmb=249376134.2.10.1335890492
>   Host    www.pemco.com.pa
>   Referer http://www.pemco.com.pa/
>   User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0
>   X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest

The Response headers however differ dramatically.  Here is the Response header from my local webserver:

> Connection    Keep-Alive
>   Content-Length  289
>   Content-Type    text/html
>   Date    Tue, 01 May 2012 15:48:05 GMT
>   Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=100
>   Server  Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) PHP/5.3.9
>   Set-Cookie  csrf_cookie_name=3473477c216fd9456d709fb0dbda10e1; expires=Tue, 01-May-2012 17:48:05 GMT; path=/ ci_session=4cmpiXkC37H53h8PD3hIRPObPeip0rCTEEYg5CDilBAi7k9J%2BesxJbu21Ls2Kbo8vSrW3ptOtEGNL1K8pGxI6%2BG1D8ZNd7%2BYiwNQG55MBRz7sAvwtIX7hVDPlyglV3DZwlOH0eCSlPFm7ZmdH46KTnwbd3%2FcftOykBlJZKlNHpdY9obcKVnYTVaCAta3fFGiM4K%2FfoqlIz%2FPCpn9Kfghv8r7fjJ7z17H8huuoWE%2FI0EmTWyag3wJxrshi80ab7JZ1c73f7cIZTpTKn7bMFB4vm9cSgu6XXBFw%2Fmx2bAoawmQHRMhQFHtBZaLcHZGHCrPwLcX3qr8KwxzfwpvKN7TzEX0GpQHJZL72CwAEA8cJ27EfzBfzx1qz8KQ4VL1W1Hq; path=/
>   X-Powered-By    PHP/5.3.9

And here is the Response header from my production web server:

> Connection    Keep-Alive
>   Content-Length  0
>   Content-Type    text/html
>   Date    Tue, 01 May 2012 16:41:51 GMT
>   Keep-Alive  timeout=15, max=90
>   MS-Author-Via   DAV
>   Server  Apache
>   Set-Cookie  csrf_cookie_name=822b8ced4d8a7bc49d02b11f44efcb15; expires=Tue, 01-May-2012 18:41:51 GMT; path=/
>   X-Powered-By    PleskLin

I can clearly see that the Response header from my production webserver is returning a Content-Length of 0, but my question is why?  As I mentioned before, I am pretty confident that all my scripts have been uploaded and configured correctly, so it has to be some type of configuration on my production webserver that is somehow affecting my script.  The URL for my corporate site is [www.pemco.com.pa](http://www.pemco.com.pa) just in case you want to check for yourselves.  My sincere appreciation in advance for any help resolving this.  I am completely stuck at this point with no idea what to do.

Comment: The ajax request for the autocomplete search is pointing to http://www.pemco.com.pa/index.php/search/suggestions - that looks suspiciously like an incorrect URL - should it not be http://www.pemco.com.pa/search/suggestions?

Comment: Same jQuery version on both servers?

Comment: thanks for your comments.  the url for the ajax request is correct.  it is not your standard url because i am using codeigniter as my php framework annd the slash segments trailing the index.php file point towards the controller/function that retrieves the content to populate the autocomplete text input.

Comment: the jquery script file is being retrieved from Google's CDN, so there is no discrepancy between the jquery versions being used.

Comment: Are there any errors being generated in the PHP that handles the AJAX request?  The ajax call is being made it's just returning nothing so my guess is there's an uncaught error in the PHP - check your error logs.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved. The problem was that my production webserver is using PHP v5.1 and native support for JSON isn't included until PHP v5.2. After installing the JSON extension using PECL I managed to solve the problem. Thanks to everyone for their feedback.